# Is SSL necessary for a school application using PINS

Tags: ssl, pins

I am developing a site for a school which will allows students to make an application using PIN and Serial No. I chooses Godaddy to Host the site on Ultimate plan, so is it necessary for me to include Standard SSL for the hosting plans since am using PINS or **Standard SSL** is meant for secure transanctions that includes using Credit cards?

Answer (score 0):

**Do you need SSL?**

I assume that said applications will contain personal data, so your web application should use SSL to prevent third parties (such as other people on the same insecure wireless network as the student) from accessing that data. Depending on your jurisdiction, you may also be required by law to enable SSL.

**Do you need GoDaddy Standard SSL?**

From a quick look, it appears that the product you are referring to is a domain-validated certificate (i.e. they only verify that you own the domain, not that you are who you say you are). You can get those significantly cheaper elsewhere, and if you launch after mid-November, you can get a free one with automatic renewal from the [Let's Encrypt](https://www.lets-encrypt.org) project.

You should also check if you can get a certificate from your school. If your application will be hosted under a domain that is already being used for the school, they may have an existing certificate that you can use. Some schools (e.g. most German universities) also have their own certificate authorities which can issue SSL certificates for arbitrary websites.

If you get your certificate from GoDaddy as well, you pay more for the convenience of not having to learn as much.